# Sum cells on the basis of other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I have, for example, the following Excel file:

```
| USER ID | SCORE | TOTAL SCORE | TOTAL BONUS | NOTE  |
| ------- | ----- | ----------- | ----------- | ----- |
| 18      | 10    |             |             |       |
| 18      | 25    |             |             |       |
| 18      | 15    |             |             |       |
| 18      | 5     |             |             | bonus |
| 18      | 30    |             |             |       |
| 24      | 2     |             |             |       |
| 24      | 7     |             |             |       |
| 24      | 21    |             |             |       |
| 32      | 6     |             |             |       |
| 32      | 9     |             |             | bonus |
| 32      | 18    |             |             |       |
| 32      | 40    |             |             |       |
```

For each USER ID, in the first row, I must have the total sum of the scores, excluding the bonuses (identifiable by the column NOTE), and separately the sum of the bonuses (if present, otherwise it will be 0).

The result of the example should be this:

```
| USER ID | SCORE | TOTAL SCORE | TOTAL BONUS | NOTE  |
| ------- | ----- | ----------- | ----------- | ----- |
| 18      | 10    | 80          | 5           |       |
| 18      | 25    |             |             |       |
| 18      | 15    |             |             |       |
| 18      | 5     |             |             | bonus |
| 18      | 30    |             |             |       |
| 24      | 2     | 30          | 0           |       |
| 24      | 7     |             |             |       |
| 24      | 21    |             |             |       |
| 32      | 6     | 64          | 9           |       |
| 32      | 9     |             |             | bonus |
| 32      | 18    |             |             |       |
| 32      | 40    |             |             |       |
```

Is it feasible to automate the sum using a function? Maybe with `SUMIF()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table starts in `A1`

```
Total Score:  C2: =IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$13,A2,$B$2:$B$13)  -SUMIFS($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13,A2,$E$2:$E$13,"bonus"))

Total Bonus:  D2: =IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIFS($B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13,A2,$E$2:$E$13,"bonus"))
```

and fill down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2697-excel-vlookup-and-sum.html):

You'll need to create some extra columns. I first calculated total score for student ID (including bonus), then total bonus, and lastly I subtracted total bonus from total score to get the desired result.

[image: excel results]

- We calculate total score and total bonus with the `SUMPRODUCT` function:
  `SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13=A2)*B2:B13)`
  First matrix is the user IDs, by which the results are grouped and summed together. The second matrix is the user score.
- We make a row in which total bonus is calculated with an IF function: `IF(F2="bonus",B2,0)`
- We calculate total bonus, very similar to the first function:
  `SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13=A2)*D2:D13)`
- We subtract total bonus from total score: `C2-E2`

After this, all that's left is cleaning up the table manually.

There's also the option to format the cells so that they're empty if their value is equal to 0 (you could apply that to the "bonus" column).

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

**TOTAL SCORE** column:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$13=A2)*$B$2:$B$13))
```

[image]

**TOTAL BONUS** column:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$13=A2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell D2:

  ```
  =IF(A2=A1,"",SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($E$2:$E$13="bonus"),$B$2:$B$13))
  ```
- Formula in cell C2:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF(A$2:A$13,A2,B$2:B$13))-D2,"")
  ```

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*